# Evaluate JSON Object recursively

Tags: java, json

We are using JSON library https://github.com/octomix/josson

My sample JSON object

```
{ "data": {
    "A": 1688,
    "B": 1363,
    "C": "calc(A+B,A:data.A,B:data.B)",
    "D": "calc(B+C,B:data.B,C:data.C)",
  "drg":"TEMPLATE(12).pdf"
  },
  "tbl02Modelmaster": {
   "A": "calc(A+100,A:$.data.A)",
    "stageType": "Multi",
    "isPowerConstraint": true
  }}
```

The JSON Object is dynamic

We want to iterate the JSON Object to get the final results with calculated value.
Also key C which is expression is used in D

```
{
  "data": {
    "A": 1688,
    "B": 1363,
    "C": 3051,
    "D": 4414,
    "drg": "TEMPLATE(12).pdf"
  },
  "tbl02Modelmaster": {
    "A": 1788.
    "stageType": "Multi",
    "isPowerConstraint": true
  }
}
```

we tried below

```
String data1 = "{\"data\":{\"A\":1688,\"B\":1363,\"C\":\"calc(A+B,A:data.A,B:data.B)\",\"D\":\"calc(B+C,B:data.B,C:data.C)\",\"drg\":\"TEMPLATE.pdf\"},\"tbl02Modelmaster\":{\"A\":\"calc(A+100,A:$.data.A)\",\"stageType\":\"Multi\",\"isPowerConstraint\":true}}";
        Josson josson1 = Josson.fromJsonString(data1);
        JsonNode node = josson1.getNode(
                "field(C: eval(data.C),D: eval(data.D))");
        System.out.println(node.toString());
```

but gives error because of C being expression and used in D

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid function call field() : Invalid function call eval() : Invalid function call calc() : Calc syntax error.
    at com.octomix.josson.FuncDispatcher.apply(FuncDispatcher.java:84)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:328)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathBySteps(JossonCore.java:249)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getPathByExpression(JossonCore.java:211)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:147)
    at com.octomix.josson.JossonCore.getNodeByExpression(JossonCore.java:142)
    at com.octomix.josson.Josson.getNode(Josson.java:279)
    at com.velotech.pumpselection.velotech.JsonArray.main(JsonArray.java:32)
```

Also the above code is hard coded, we want to iterate the JSON Object as we do not know the structure of JSON Object

**UPDATE**

To bifurcate between normal string and expression, I have modified the source json structure

```
{
  "data": {
    "A": 1688,
    "B": 1363,
    "C": {
      "expression": "calc(A+B,A:data.A,B:data.B)"
    },
    "D": {
      "expression": "calc(B+C,B:data.B,C:data.C)"
    },
    "drg": "TEMPLATE(12).pdf"
  },
  "tbl02Modelmaster": {
    "A": {
      "expression": "calc(A+100,A:$.data.A)"
    },
    "stageType": "Multi",
    "isPowerConstraint": true
  }
}
```

Output Required

```
{
  "data": {
    "A": 1688,
    "B": 1363,
    "C": 3051,
    "D": 4414,
    "drg": "TEMPLATE(12).pdf"
  },
  "tbl02Modelmaster": {
    "A": 1788.
    "stageType": "Multi",
    "isPowerConstraint": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Josson* uses library [mXparser](https://mathparser.org/) for maths calculation. After testing, it seems that upper case "C" is a reserved word. I changed it to lower case "c" and the syntax error has gone.

```
Josson josson1 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{\"data\": {" +
    "    \"A\": 1688," +
    "    \"B\": 1363," +
    "    \"c\": \"?.calc(A+B)\"," +
    "    \"D\": \"?.calc(B+c)\"," +
    "    \"drg\":\"TEMPLATE(12).pdf\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"tbl02Modelmaster\": {" +
    "    \"A\": \"?.calc(A+100,A:$.data.A)\"," +
    "    \"stageType\": \"Multi\"," +
    "    \"isPowerConstraint\": true" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
```

**Transformation expression**

```
JsonNode node = josson1.getNode(
    "field(data" +
    "      .field(c: eval(c))" +
    "      .field(D: eval(D))" +
    ")" +
    ".field(tbl02Modelmaster" +
    "       .field(A: eval(A))" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "data" : {
    "A" : 1688,
    "B" : 1363,
    "c" : 3051.0,
    "D" : 4414.0,
    "drg" : "TEMPLATE(12).pdf"
  },
  "tbl02Modelmaster" : {
    "A" : 1788.0,
    "stageType" : "Multi",
    "isPowerConstraint" : true
  }
}
```

**Build the transformation expression**

Due to the JSON structure is unknown, you can build the transformation expression on the fly. In order to avoid the evaluation of `TEMPLATE(12)` which will throw `UnsupportedFunctionException`, I added a specific pattern `?.` to the beginning of the object values that need to be evaluated. The following query find out all the entries that the value starts with `?.` to construct the expression.

```
String expression = josson1.getString(
    "entries()" +
    ".concat('field('," +
    "        key," +
    "        value.entries()" +
    "             .[value =~ '\\?\\..*']*" +
    "             .concat('.field(',key,': eval(',key,'))')" +
    "             .join()," +
    "        ')')" +
    ".join('.')");
System.out.println(expression);
JsonNode node = josson1.getNode(expression);
:
:
```

**Output**

```
field(data.field(c: eval(c)).field(D: eval(D))).field(tbl02Modelmaster.field(A: eval(A)))
```

---

**Solution for "UPDATE" question**

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"data\": {" +
    "    \"A\": 1688," +
    "    \"B\": 1363," +
    "    \"c\": {" +
    "      \"expression\": \"calc(A+B)\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"D\": {" +
    "      \"expression\": \"calc(B+c)\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"drg\": \"TEMPLATE(12).pdf\"" +
    "  }," +
    "  \"tbl02Modelmaster\": {" +
    "    \"A\": {" +
    "      \"expression\": \"calc(A+100,A:$.data.A)\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    \"stageType\": \"Multi\"," +
    "    \"isPowerConstraint\": true" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode(
    "field(data" +
    "      .field(c: eval(c.expression))" +
    "      .field(D: eval(D.expression))" +
    ")" +
    ".field(tbl02Modelmaster" +
    "       .field(A: eval(A.expression))" +
    ")");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "data" : {
    "A" : 1688,
    "B" : 1363,
    "c" : 3051.0,
    "D" : 4414.0,
    "drg" : "TEMPLATE(12).pdf"
  },
  "tbl02Modelmaster" : {
    "A" : 1788.0,
    "stageType" : "Multi",
    "isPowerConstraint" : true
  }
}
```

**Build the transformation expression**

```
String expression = josson.getString(
    "entries()" +
    ".concat('field('," +
    "        key," +
    "        value.entries()" +
    "             .[value.expression!=null]*" +
    "             .concat('.field(',key,': eval(',key,'.expression))')" +
    "             .join()," +
    "        ')')" +
    ".join('.')");
```

**Output**

```
field(data.field(c: eval(c.expression)).field(D: eval(D.expression))).field(tbl02Modelmaster.field(A: eval(A.expression)))
```

Comment: thanks @Raymond choi. This above transformation equation works well. But what if the JSON structure has more depth. Can we iterate to any depth

Comment: One issue is how to avoid evaluation of String which has bracket as part of string. eg modified the above json "drg":"TEMPLATE(12).pdf". Here can we add some if statement to check if(eval(drg).isNull(), drg, eval(drg)

Comment: It can't.  `TEMPLATE(12)` will throw an `UnsupportedFunctionException` and can't be catch inside the statement.  I think you can specifically define a pattern for the value that needs to be evaluated. e.g. starts with `?.` where `?` means the current node.  Then the value becomes `?.calc(A+B)` and the regex becomes `'\?\..*'`.

Comment: BTW.  It seems that you used my solutions on _Josson_ of you previous questions. But never "Accept" them :)

Comment: your answers are helping me a lot. Thanks for your efforts. I have edited my JSON structure in "UPDATE" to bifurcate expression. Could you please let me know how to eval only parameter with only "expression"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, mXparser has a lot of reserved keywords. The most convenient way is to set mXparser to automatic keyword overwriting mode by using the option:

```
mXparser.setToOverrideBuiltinTokens();
```

This should solve all problems.