# JSON Evaluation issue with JSON Array

Tags: java, json

We are using JSON library https://github.com/octomix/josson

Also Refer issue and answer on [Evaluate JSON Object recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563953/evaluate-json-object-recursively)

My sample JSON

```
{
  "data": {
    "A": "717.5",
    "B": {
      "expression": "calc(205+42*A,A:$.selectedPump.stg)"
    },
    "E": {
      "expression": "calc(A+B)"
    },
    "D": "96",
    "D1": "96",
    "MotorWt": "28.5"
  },
  "selectedPump": {
    "termsHtrimSolarMotor": [
      -7.372112927801618,
      8.837084474924652,
      -1.1152401096382207
    ],
    "overallEffEq": "[-0.0013252914566755647, 0.10052143733055335, -0.005975385931287854]",
    "stg":1
  }
}
```

JAVA Code to calculate only when the formula is given in "expression"

```
String json="{\"data\":{\"A\":\"717.5\",\"B\":{\"expression\":\"calc(205+42*A,A:$.selectedPump.stg)\"},\"E\":{\"expression\":\"calc(A+B)\"},\"D\":\"96\",\"D1\":\"96\",\"MotorWt\":\"28.5\"},\"selectedPump\":{\"termsHtrimSolarMotor\":[-7.372112927801618,8.837084474924652,-1.1152401096382207],\"overallEffEq\":\"[-0.0013252914566755647,0.10052143733055335,-0.005975385931287854]\",\"stg\":1}}";
        
        Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(json);
        
        String expression = josson.getString(
                "entries()" +
                ".concat('field('," +
                "        key," +
                "        value.entries()" +
                "             .[value.expression!=null]*" +
                "             .concat('.field(',key,': eval(',key,'.expression))')" +
                "             .join()," +
                "        ')')" +
                ".join('.')");
            System.out.println(expression);
            
            JsonNode node=josson.getNode(expression);
            System.out.println(node.toString());
```

Output

```
field(data.field(B: eval(B.expression)).field(E: eval(E.expression))).field(selectedPump.field(termsHtrimSolarMotor: eval(termsHtrimSolarMotor.expression)))


{"data":{"A":"717.5","B":247.0,"E":964.5,"D":"96","D1":"96","MotorWt":"28.5"},"selectedPump":{"termsHtrimSolarMotor":[],"overallEffEq":"[-0.0013252914566755647,0.10052143733055335,-0.005975385931287854]","stg":1}}
```

here the key "termsHtrimSolarMotor" which is a array is evaluated even if it doesn't have expression and give empty array in result
**"termsHtrimSolarMotor":[]**

Thanks
Pranav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `[value.expression!=null]*` , `value.expression` for termsHtrimSolarMotor is an empty array and therefore it is not null.

Please try `[isText(value.expression)]*`