# Filter JSON Data upto 2nd or 3rd Level

Tags: java, json

Original Post: [Evaluate JSON Object recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563953/evaluate-json-object-recursively)

We are using JSON library https://github.com/octomix/josson

we have JSON Object as below

```
{
  "selectionModel": {
    "dp_speed": "0",
    "moc": "CI-0"
  },
  "data": {
    "B": "220",
    "h2": "1000",
    "h6": "175",
    "weight": {
      "expression": "calc(B+h2)"
    },
    "height": {
      "expression": "calc(B+h6)"
    },
    "columnPipe": {
      "pipeTotalWeight": {
        "expression": "calc(if(length==0,680,700),length:$.data.columnPipe.pipeTotalLength)"
      },
      "pipeTotalLength": 1200,
      "PipeCapLiters": {
        "expression": "calc(if(length==0,70,100),length:$.data.columnPipe.pipeTotalLength)"
      },
      "pipeTopPipeqty": 1
    }
  },
  "tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge": {
    "flangeId": 3835,
    "flangetype": "RF",
    "size": 150
  }
}
```

Required Output

```
{
  "selectionModel": {
    "dp_speed": "0",
    "moc": "CI-0"
  },
  "data": {
    "B": "220",
    "h2": "1000",
    "h6": "175",
    "weight": 1220.0,
    "height": 395.0,
    "columnPipe": {
      "pipeTotalWeight": 700.0,
      "pipeTotalLength": 1200,
      "PipeCapLiters": 100.0,
      "pipeTopPipeqty": 1
    }
  },
  "tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge": {
    "flangeId": 3835,
    "flangetype": "RF",
    "size": 150
  }
}
```

As suggested in original post we are able to evaluate only 1st Level i.e till **data** node and not till **data.columnPipe** node as below

```
String a = "{\"selectionModel\":{\"dp_speed\":\"0\",\"moc\":\"CI-0\"},\"data\":{\"B\":\"220\",\"h2\":\"1000\",\"h6\":\"175\",\"weight\":{\"expression\":\"calc(B+h2)\"},\"height\":{\"expression\":\"calc(B+h6)\"},\"columnPipe\":{\"pipeTotalWeight\":{\"expression\":\"calc(if(length==0,680,700),length:$.data.columnPipe.pipeTotalLength)\"},\"pipeTotalLength\":1200,\"PipeCapLiters\":{\"expression\":\"calc(if(length==0,70,100),length:$.data.columnPipe.pipeTotalLength)\"},\"pipeTopPipeqty\":1}},\"tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge\":{\"flangeId\":3835,\"flangetype\":\"RF\",\"size\":150}}";

Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(a);

String expression = josson.getString("entries()" + ".concat('field('," + "        key," + "        value.entries()"
                + "             .[isNotEmpty(value.expression)]*" + "             .concat('.field(',key,': eval(',key,'.expression))')"
                + "             .join()," + "        ')')" + ".join('.')");

System.out.println(expression);
System.out.println(josson.getNode(expression));
```

Output of above code

```
field(selectionModel).field(data.field(weight: eval(weight.expression)).field(height: eval(height.expression))).field(tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge)

{"selectionModel":{"dp_speed":"0","moc":"CI-0"},"data":{"B":"220","h2":"1000","h6":"175","weight":1220.0,"height":395.0,"columnPipe":{"pipeTotalWeight":{"expression":"calc(if(length==0,680,700),length:$.data.columnPipe.pipeTotalLength)"},"pipeTotalLength":1200,"PipeCapLiters":{"expression":"calc(if(length==0,70,100),length:$.data.columnPipe.pipeTotalLength)"},"pipeTopPipeqty":1}},"tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge":{"flangeId":3835,"flangetype":"RF","size":150}}
```

As you see we are only able to query till 1st Level

Required Output

```
field(selectionModel).field(data.field(weight: eval(weight.expression)).field(height: eval(height.expression)).field(columnPipe.field(PipeCapLiters: eval(PipeCapLiters.expression)).field(pipeTotalWeight: eval(pipeTotalWeight.expression)))).field(tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge)

{"selectionModel":{"dp_speed":"0","moc":"CI-0"},"data":{"B":"220","h2":"1000","h6":"175","weight":1220.0,"height":395.0,"columnPipe":{"pipeTotalWeight":700.0,"pipeTotalLength":1200,"PipeCapLiters":100.0,"pipeTopPipeqty":1}},"tbl05FlangeMasterDischarge":{"flangeId":3835,"flangetype":"RF","size":150}}
```

how do we concat expression till 2nd level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding transformation expression is this:

```
field(data
      .field(weight: eval(weight.expression),
             height: eval(height.expression),
             columnPipe.field(pipeTotalWeight: eval(pipeTotalWeight.expression),
                              PipeCapLiters: eval(PipeCapLiters.expression)
             ),
      )
)
```

The question is how to build this expression from your JSON object.  It's a little bit complicated. I found a solution is to flatten the JSON to filter all `.expression` elements first, and then reconstruct the JSON.  The next step is to build the transformation expression from the reconstructed JSON.

```
String expression = josson.getString(
    "flatten('_').~'.*_expression$'*.get(..).map(key::value).mergeObjects().unflatten('_')" +
    ".concat('field('," +
    "        entries()" +
    "        .concat(key," +
    "                '.field('," +
    "                value" +
    "                  .entries()" +
    "                  .concat(key," +
    "                          if([isNotEmpty(value.expression)]," +
    "                             concat(': eval(', key, '.expression)')," +
    "                             concat('.field('," +
    "                                    value" +
    "                                      .entries()" +
    "                                      .concat(key, ': eval(', key, '.expression)')" +
    "                                      .join(',')," +
    "                                    ')'" +
    "                             )" +
    "                          )" +
    "                   )" +
    "                  .join(',')," +
    "                ')'" +
    "         )" +
    "        .join(',')," +
    "        ')'" +
    " )");
```